# Alter an specific row from a group id by the max value in each group

Tags: r, indexing, filter, group-by, data-manipulation

I have a data set in R of 1.5 million rows and 23 columns, which looks like:

```
ID  Week col1 col2 col3 ...
A   1    2    3    1
A   2    3    4    1
...
A   69   15   2    11
B   1    5    1    2
B   2    6    10   3
...
B   69   2    1    1
Z   1    1    12   2
Z   2    4    5    3
...
Z   69   1    20   2
```

I want to alter each ID but only in the "Week" 69, with one third of the Max value of each group ID

For example:
Max value for ID = A in the col1, divided by 3 and replace it in the original data set.

My current logic, which seems not be working:

```
index<-unique(data$ID)
dat<-filter(data, id== index[1])

b<-sapply(dat[,3:23],max)
b<-b/3
dat[69,4:23]<-dat[69,4:23]+b
data.alt<-dat
enter code here
for (i in 2:19477)
{
dat<-filter(data, id== index[i])

b<-sapply(dat[,4:23],max)
b<-b/3
dat[69,4:23]<-dat[69,4:23]+b
data.alt<-rbind(data.alt,dat)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `data.table` methods.  Create a vector of `names` from the original dataset where there is `col` in the column names ('nm1'), `paste` with 'i.' to create second vector ('nm2' - for assigning the values while joining), then summarise the datasets with the `max` of 'cols's grouped by 'ID' and specifying the `.SDcols` as 'nm1', create a column 'Week' as '69', `join` the two datasets `on`, 'ID', 'Week' and assign (`:=`) the values of 'nm2' to 'nm1' columns

```
library(data.table)
nm1 <- grep("col", names(df1), value = TRUE)
nm2 <- paste0("i.", nm1)
df2 <- setDT(df1)[, lapply(.SD, max) , ID, .SDcols = nm1][, Week := factor(69)][]
df1[df2, (nm1) := mget(nm2), on = .(ID, Week)]
df1
```

#### Update

If we want to replace the `max` value divided by 3 for 'nm1' columns where 'Week' is 69,

```
setDT(df1)[, (nm1) := lapply(.SD, as.numeric), .SDcol = nm1]
df2 <-  df1[, lapply(.SD, function(x) max(x)/3) , ID, .SDcols = nm1][, Week := factor(69)][]
df1[df2, (nm1) := mget(nm2), on = .(ID, Week)]
```

#### Update2

If we need to `add` to the original values, change the last line of code to

```
df1[df2,  (nm1) := Map(`+`, mget(nm1), mget(nm2)), on = .(ID, Week)]
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(ID = c("A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "Z", "Z", 
"Z"), Week = structure(c(1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L), .Label = c("1", 
"2", "69"), class = "factor"), col1 = c(2L, 3L, 15L, 5L, 6L, 
2L, 1L, 4L, 1L), col2 = c(3L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 10L, 1L, 12L, 5L, 20L
), col3 = c(1L, 1L, 11L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 2L)), .Names = c("ID", 
"Week", "col1", "col2", "col3"), row.names = c(NA, -9L), 
class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. I need to add one third of the max value, not the max and second, in my original data, week is a factor, in case I need to conserve data types by column the merge do not work: x.'week' is a factor column being joined to i.'week' which is type 'double'.

Comment: @Michelle   Changed the code based on your comments